# PHP - preg_match - Match a !word, or match !word followed by word(s)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to find a regex pattern to match the following with a pattern(without their quotes):

"!comm" - Matches, match(0) = !comm, match(1) = comm

"!comm param1 param2" - Matches, match(0) = !comm param1 param2, match(1) = comm, match(2) = param1 param2

"!comm " - Should not match

I started as following:

```
$string1 = "!comm";
$string2 = "!comm param1 param2";
$string3 = "!comm ";

preg_match("`!(.*?)$`", $string1, $match1);
preg_match("`!(.*?)\s(.*)$`", $string2, $match2);
preg_match("`!(.*?)\S$`", $string3, $match3);

echo "<h1>Test 1</h1>";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($match1);
print_r($match2);
print_r($match3);
echo "</pre>";
```

This gives the exact output I'd like, just that they're not generalized and working as individuals only:

```
Array
(
    [0] => !comm
    [1] => comm
)
Array
(
    [0] => !comm param1 param2
    [1] => comm
    [2] => param1 param2
)
Array
(
)
```

Then tried to merge them as:

```
`!(.+)($|\s(.*)$|\S$)`
```

But obviously failed, and I know I'm thinking wrong. I tried a few anothers, though I haven't save them up, I were mostly blind-shooting after some time Googling. Look-ahead ways, or if/else ways, either have ended having "!comm param1 param2" and "!comm " match or just each as individual.

I do feel this is doable in RegEx, but I'm still too new in RegEx, and I feel that my way of thinking hasn't found it's place yet. So more than the fully functional RegEx ready for use, I would like a step-by-step process to achieve this such thing.

Comment: You may want to look into RegexBuddy - useful for writing more complex regex.

Comment: @Eli Thank you. However although it does look useful, and I keep hearing about it, I would rather a freeware solution, as I cannot possibly afford it right now, and as well I'm only experimenting RegEx in a non-commercial way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can combine the patterns into this:

```
`^!(\S+)(?:\s+(\S+.*))?+$`
```

1. start with "!"
2. "comm" should be non-space characters.
3. then followed by nothing or any numbers of spaces and param strings

Comment: First off, thank you, it works flawlessly, I'm trying to understand it. We matched the command word as anything but space, repeated {0,} times, where when there's no character, the match won't occur, this also does seem to omit empty matches(?). Then within passive group(thanks again, as I got to know about this too!), [either followed by a space(I changed this part from \s+ to \s, as only single space is what I need) and then followed by anything], or [nothing at all]. What I actually don't get is the ?+ part. Since we already started greedy (\S.*) part, isn't ?/{0,1} all we need?

Comment: Oh, yes, "once or not all all" is all we need. No need to use this possessive quantifier although it works in this case.